# How to use GDB to debug a kernel with custom GDT? (Breakpoints Failed)

Tags: operating-system, gdb, qemu

I'm using QEMU to emulate a mini OS.

The kernel was linked with the **virtual address** entry point located at **0xC0100000**. (All symbols' addresses in file kernel are higher than 0xC0100000)

After bootloader loaded kernel on the **physical address** **0x00100000**, it setted a **global descriptor table** which makes so that virtual address space beyond 0xC0100000 is mapped to physical address 0x00100000, then long jumped to the kernel entry point.

When I'm using GDB to debug the kernel, it **ignores all breakpoints** setted in kernel.

The GDB still assumes my kernel code is located at 0xC0100000, however, kernel code is located at 0x00100000. When I set breakpoints using physical addresses it could hit but raises issues in later execution.

**How to** make GDB does not ignore the existence of custom GDT?